# "with your not trusting yourself"

Tags: prepositions, pronouns, determiners

The following quoted sentence is a dialogue, spoken by a therapist to the male protagonist from the series 'The Affair'.

> These feelings you have for Alison (male protagonist’s wife) judging you, not trusting you, that they really have more to do ***with your*** not trusting yourself.

---

Why is **"your"** used here and not **"you"**? Is there any difference between "with you" and "with your" **in this context**?

Comment: Are you watching it with subtitles? Maybe it's a type mistake in the subtitle.

Comment: There wasn’t any mistake. The subtitles and the verbals matched perfectly.

Comment: It's correct. It's equivalent to "more to do with your lack of trust in yourself". "Not trusting yourself" is functioning as a noun here.

Comment: Okay but what rules are applied in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in the meanings. The clause "your not  trusting yourself" is a gerund-participial clause.  When it is a complement or object, as it is here, it can take either a genitive (**your**) or accusative (**you**) subject.

See this reference:
[Google Books "A Student's Introduction..."](https://tinyurl.com/y922nw3p)
"Here, and in most other complement functions, we find both genitive and non-genitive subjects."

There are some guidelines about the choice that are visible there at the link to Google Books.